# Atom Interferometer Contrast

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, interferometry, cold-atoms

I have made a simulation of a Raman beam based atom interferometer in a Mach-Zehnder configuration. In this way, the electronic state of the atom changes as well as the momentum when diffraction by the Raman beams occurs, such that $|g_1,p_0\rangle\to|g_2,p_0+\hbar K\rangle$ where $p_0$ is the initial momentum $\hbar K$ is the momentum gained from two-photon recoil and $g_1$ and $g_2$ are two electronic ground states normally separated by a hyperfine transition.

After the interrogation time through the interferometer, the atoms are detected by shining resonant light on either or both of the two states phase information is acquired by a varying population in those states.

The output of the simulation which includes finite atomic temperature resulting in contrast reduction is shown in the figure below. The system is first initialized in the $|g_1,p_0\rangle$ ground state. The plot is acquired by scanning over the laser phase of the last Raman beam splitter. The output makes sense to me as the finite temperature means that many of the atoms don't meet the resonant condition for diffraction by the Raman laser beams this is reflected in the difference in the mean amplitude of the two states and the fringe amplitudes.

[image: Output as a function of laser phase]

My question is, how do we interpret the contrast of the interferometer? If we take the usual expression for contrast
$$C=\frac{I_{max}-I_{min}}{I_{max}+I_{min}}$$
where $I$ is the signal intensity, we now have two different contrasts for the two states (0.1 blue, 0.3 orange).

So the question is, for this type of interferometer where the two states can be detected independently, can there be two different contrasts?

I don't think this is the right question to get into the weeds of the simulation so first verifying whether or not the contrast can be different for the two states would be a good starting point.